# How to ensure some custom ID has not been created already in the past?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with some `charField` called `custom_id`.

I am generating this ID randomly, and check if already exists in database before assigning it.

So all my `custom_id`s are unique.

However if I delete some entry from the database. The `custom_id` will become available again. I want to prevent that. I want the `custom_id` not to be ever usable again.

How is that possible ? Is there a clean way to achieve that ?

Comment: How do you generate your IDs? If there is a large enough pool of IDs the probability of actually generating two same ids might be so small that it's not necessary to think about this

Comment: Probably you could try UUID. Chance that a UUID could be duplicated ~1/2^128

Comment: No my IDs are quite small : they have some probability to be the same at some point. I can not use UUID for specs reasons.

Comment: You could not delete from database, but add a column like `is_delete` to fake deleting it.

Comment: That could be a solution, tho that would require me to change how I query all the objects, and always filtering them by `is_deleted=False` + doing that my database won't stop growing... I wonder if there is not something better I can do

Comment: You can change the default `objects` manager to always filter by `is_deleted=False`, see [the manager docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) - then you don't need to change the other queries.

Comment: @lapin as you said, you IDs are quite small, I think storing them, which had been used , somewhere is simple.

Comment: What is the limit for charField? A timestamp + random solution ensures the IDs are not used in past. Addition of check to ensure if it already exists makes sure they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in a try-catch block.
since the custom_id field is unique, while inserting into DB it will throw integrity error if custom id already exists. 
You can do whatever you want in catch block custom_id is already exist.

Comment: If the `custom_id` was deleted from DB, the try block will succeed right ? However I want to be sure that the IDs are unique, including among the ones that were deleted.